# ModelMapper: apply rule to all fields of type

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have a DTO with a lot of String fields (some are of other types).
When mapping objects into objects of another similar class, I need to apply a transformation to all fields of type String, in this case - `trim()`.

So, I have:

```
class MyDTO {
  String name;
  String type;
  String company;
  String status;
  String whatever;
  ... (there are about 80 String fields)
  int someNumber;
  double otherNumber;
}
```

```
class DestinationDTO { // has just some fields of MyDTO
  String name;
  String type;
  String company;
  String whatever;
  int somenumber;
}
```

What I've tried:

```
Converter<String, String> myConverter = c -> c.getSource().trim();
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
...
mm.typeMap(MyDTO.class, DestinationDTO.class)
  .addMappings(c -> c
      .using(myConverter)
      .map(MyDTO::getName, DestinationDTO::getName)
    ) // this applies to just one field, I need all String fields
```

Is there a way to specify all String fields of a class at once, instead of having to list them?

Tried searching the modelmapper.org docs, but all I see is configuring fields one by one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Have you tried converters?

Comment: Yes I have tried them. Updated my question with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [converters](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/) to specify transformations from one type to another. The source and target type can be the same. Use the [`addConverter<S,D>()`](http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.html#addConverter-org.modelmapper.Converter-) method to add a general converter to the ModelMapper itself (rather than individually to a specific field). You can use it like this:

```
ModelMapper mm = new ModelMapper();
Converter<String, String> myConverter = new AbstractConverter<String, String>() {
    protected String convert(String source) {
        return source == null ? null : source.trim();
    }
};
mm.addConverter(myConverter);
mm.getConfiguration().setFieldMatchingEnabled(true);
MyDTO source = new MyDTO();
source.name = "   abc    \t";
source.company = "\nd   e  f  \n";

DestinationDTO target = mm.map(source, DestinationDTO.class);
System.out.printf("Target.name: '%s'%n", target.name);
System.out.printf("Target.company: '%s'%n", target.company);
```

The output will be as expected:

```
Target.name: 'abc'
Target.company: 'd   e  f'
```

Comment: @kit see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67937978/6413377) also. You can set the converter at "root level" of mapper as in this answer is done but in that case the implementation needs to extend AbstractConverter (as also done in this answer). For some reason implementing interface Converter will not have the same effect.

Comment: That AbstractConverter was the tricky part. Wish this use case was documented properly...

Anyway, I was able to achieve what I needed.
I guess, if the converter is set using `.createTypeMap()`, it's also being set sorta at the "root level", since the rule will apply to all `<String, String>` fields.

Would be good if it would be possible to add the converter for a specific <Source, Destination> pair though